# скорость поиска в базе данных

Tags: postgresql

Какой поиск быстрее работает: по первичному ключу типа long,  или по первичному ключу типа String, и какая разница?

Где-то слышал, что бд устроена примерно как HashMap, и поиск по любому key, независимо от типа key, занимает const.

Comment: Даже когда дерево строится по значению хеш-функции сам ключ в индекс все равно включается.  А чем длинее ключ, тем больше места на диске занимает индекс. А чем больше он занял места тем больше вероятность, что следующая ветвь дерева лежит в отдельной странице, следовательно больше страниц придется поднимать с диска да и головкам дальше бегать по большому индексу (хотя конечно часто файлы используют, а не сырые диски и там может менее заметно из за фрагментации)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***PostgreSQL*** только в тегах, но ответ зависит от РСУБД, так что предположу его.

---

> Где-то слышал, что бд устроена примерно как HashMap, и поиск по любому key независимо от типа key занимает const.

**Необязательно, по умолчанию нет.** Это зависит от типа индекса. Для [первичных ключей в PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-types.html) по умолчанию используется [**структура данных B-дерево**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE):

> Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique btree index on the column or group of columns used in the primary key.

Хэш-индекс, заставляющий базу делать поиск на манер хэш-таблицы, [**не рекомендован**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-types.html):

> Hash index operations are not presently WAL-logged, so hash *indexes might need to be rebuilt with `REINDEX` after a database crash* if there were unwritten changes. Also, *changes to hash indexes are not replicated over streaming or file-based replication after the initial base backup*, so they give wrong answers to queries that subsequently use them. For these reasons, hash index use is presently discouraged.

(далее вольный перевод) ...поскольку может потребовать полного перестроения при падении БД, а также изменения в нём не реплицируются через файлы и потоки, из-за чего запросы с их использованием могут давать неправильные ответы.

---

Что касается "что быстрее", ответ всегда один: измерьте в ваших условиях и получите однозначный ответ. Типа данных `long` [в PostgreSQL нет](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype.html).

Асимптотика поиска в хэш-таблице (ваш "const", aka `O(1)`) не имеет к этому никакого отношения, поскольку в асимптотику не включен "константный множитель".  Множитель в данном случае зависит от скорости одного сравнения двух значений одного типа. Для разных типов он будет разным, а асимптотика при той же структуре данных (том же типе индекса) будет прежней.

Для 4 или 8-байтных целых чисел сравнение в общем случае быстрее, чем для строк, хотя бы потому что они фиксированной (и маленькой) длины.

Comment: спасибо за развёрнутый ответ